# Missing jruby-win32ole gem on a rails app error / warning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, jrubyonrails, jruby-win32ole

I am seeing an odd error (*probably actually a warning as it does not appear to halt the processes*) on my Linux and OS X production and development environments where it's throwing:

```
!!!! Missing jruby-win32ole gem: jruby -S gem install jruby-win32ole
```

This happens from any execution of rails, such as even simply: `rails s`

Is there any reason that this should be showing up on a unix system when thre'there's obviously no need for an OLE adapter?  Further, there is nothing in the app that should evoke this kind of requirement that I can find.

Just would like some light shed on this if possible.

Comment: What version of Rails are you running?  Have you checked to see if this gem is in your Gemfile?

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem ?